# How to get rid of 'Name ... used only once: possible typo at ...'?

Tags: perl, perl-module

```
use YAML::XS;
local $YAML::XS::DumpCode=1;
...
```

I get the warning:

```
Name "YAML::XS::DumpCode" used only once: possible typo at ..
```

Well, I know I can suppress this specific warning, but it's kind'a ugly. Am I doing anything wrong? I'm not used to be warned :)

Answer (score 18):

It seems like `$YAML::XS::DumpCode` is only used from C code, and it is never initialized in `YAML/XS.pm` (it is there, but commented out).  So that might be a bug to submit against that module.

In the mean time, `no warnings 'once';` should do the trick.

Comment: The same warning goes for `local $YAML::UseCode=1;`. Is that the same case? Anothr bug (this time in `YAML` itself)?

Comment: @David => the "other tools" link on every cpan release page contains a grep tool to quickly search all the files in the release.  I'd recommend doing a search for `UseCode` and see how it is used in the module.

Answer (score 0):

There is no global variable declared with the name `$YAML::XS::DumpCode`. This configuration is in the `YAML` class, so you should set it with `local $YAML::DumpCode = 1;`: see [the documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/YAML/lib/YAML.pm#GLOBAL_OPTIONS).

Comment: Are you sure?  The C code seems to use the XS one:  `((gv = gv_fetchpv("YAML::XS::DumpCode", TRUE, SVt_PV)) &&`

Comment: @Eric: it's not documented, and there is a documented `$YAML::DumpCode`, so IMHO that variable shouldn't be there at all. The XS should be using `$YAML::DumpCode`.

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~ingy/YAML-LibYAML-0.34/lib/YAML/XS.pm#CONFIGURATION explicitly discusses `$YAML::XS::UseCode`.

Comment: @David: hmm, this seems really fishy.. why should configs be scattered across the implementation modules when they should just use the ones in `YAML`? But okay, given the documentation, Eric's response is correct. :)